# Implement segment.io with angular2

Tags: angular

How to implement segment.io with angular2. I included the script provided by segment.com in my index file. It dose track all page which are reloaded but dose not track any other routes changes(without reload). Is there any nice documentation which I can follow to go through implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should paste init script into html head tag and remove this line `analytics.page();` and call this function on route change event

```
router.events.distinctUntilChanged((previous: any, current: any) => {
  if (current instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    return previous.url === current.url;
  }
  return true;
}).subscribe((x: any) => {
  console.log('router.change', x);
  analytics.page();
});
```